# How to use keypress event in an iframe input from its parent page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

Assume I have an iframe in my HTML webpage that contains a part of my HTML data. It has an input for a search text box. I want, when I write something inside the input, using onkeypress event, I can show the data in the span.

How can I do this?

I read many different suggestions but none of them worked correctly for me!
Note that pages are at same domain but I don't have access to the iframe page code!
Can anyone help me writing it?

Here is the simplified code of what I need:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  

$('#iframeDoc').ready(function(){
$(this).contents().on('keypress', function(event) { 
  // add pressed keys to span });
});
$('#iframeDoc').attr("src","JavaScript:'iframe content'");

});
```

Main page HTML:

```
<html>
<body>
<iframe id="iframeDoc" src="iframepage.html"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

iframepage html:

```
<html>
<body>
<input type="text" />

<span id="result"></span>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A generic function to capture any keyup events within the iframe, e.g.

```
$(document.getElementById('frame-id').contentWindow.document).keyup(function(e){
     //code here
});
```

Separately you can access elements in iframes with code like (note that I added an ID to your input element):

```
$('#iframe').contents().find('#element_id');
```

So putting them together, could you not do something like:

```
$(document.getElementById('frame-id').contentWindow.document).keyup(function(e){
   if($('#iframe').contents().find('#element_id').is(":focus")){
      //code here
   }       
});
```

Fiddle of what I think is  working example for your code:

https://jsfiddle.net/42j45kmn/7/

Comment: I tried this solution in the parent in our current project, but it didnt seem to work. Is this no longer possible to do?

Comment: only just saw this - if you can make a jsfiddle of how it's not working for you I might have a suggestion. I'd be disappointed if this is no longer possible